# babel source maps - cant debug properly

Tags: node.js, async-await, babeljs, source-maps, babel-polyfill

i am working on a university project and am writing the backend with node js transpiled with babel in order to use async/await

i am generating source maps in order to debug properly but its doing some pretty shitty job

for example - i cant put a breakpoint on an "if" or a "return" statement
i fear this has happened only after installing some extra babel plugins i had to install while trying to resolve some errors

here's my package.json:

```
"axios": "^0.15.3",
"babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
"body-parser": "^1.15.2",
"chai": "^3.5.0",
"chai-datetime": "^1.4.1",
"ejs": "^2.5.2",
"exceljs": "^0.2.39",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"flat": "^2.0.1",
"generator": "^1.0.1",
"hash": "^0.2.0",
"hash-generator": "^0.1.0",
"mocha": "^3.2.0",
"moment": "^2.17.1",
"mongoose": "^4.7.2",
"nodemailer": "^2.7.0",
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
"react-bootstrap-table": "^2.9.0",
"react-dom": "^15.4.1",
"react-router": "^3.0.0",
"react-uniform": "^1.2.1",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
"winston": "^2.3.0",
"winston-mongodb": "^1.6.5"


"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
"babel-core": "^6.21.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.20.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
"babel-preset-es2016": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
"babel-watch": "^2.0.4",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
"webpack": "^1.13.3",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
```

its a bit cut but you get the point

the weird thing is that the transpiled js file look oddly weird

```
var addEncouragement = function () {
var _ref = (0, _asyncToGenerator3.default)(_regenerator2.default.mark(function _callee(sessionId, encouragementDetails) {
    var user, encouragement, i, exist, products, res;
    return _regenerator2.default.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
        while (1) {
            switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
                case 0:
                    logger.info('Services.Encouragement.index.addEncouragement', { 'session-id': sessionId });
                    _context.next = 3;
                    return permissions.validatePermissionForSessionId(sessionId, 'addEncouragement');

                case 3:
                    user = _context.sent;

                    if (!(user != null)) {
                        _context.next = 29;
                        break;
                    }

                    encouragement = new encouragementModel();

                    encouragement.active = encouragementDetails.active;
                    encouragement.numOfProducts = encouragementDetails.numOfProducts;
                    encouragement.rate = encouragementDetails.rate;

                    //check if all the products id belongs to products
                    i = 0;

                case 10:
                    if (!(i < encouragementDetails.products.length)) {
                        _context.next = 19;
                        break;
                    }

                    _context.next = 13;
                    return dal.getProductById(encouragementDetails.products[i]);

                case 13:
                    exist = _context.sent;

                    if (!(exist == null)) {
                        _context.next = 16;
                        break;
                    }

                    return _context.abrupt('return', { 'encouragement': null, 'code': 404, 'err': 'product not found' });

                case 16:
                    i++;
                    _context.next = 10;
                    break;

                case 19:
                    _context.next = 21;
                    return dal.getProductsById(encouragementDetails);

                case 21:
                    products = _context.sent;

                    encouragement.products = products;

                    _context.next = 25;
                    return dal.addEncouragement(encouragement);

                case 25:
                    res = _context.sent;
                    return _context.abrupt('return', { 'encouragement': encouragement, 'code': 200, 'err': null });

                case 29:
                    return _context.abrupt('return', { 'encouragement': null, 'code': 401, 'err': 'permission denied' });

                case 30:
                case 'end':
                    return _context.stop();
            }
        }
    }, _callee, this);
}));
```

while this is the source function:

```
let addEncouragement = async function(sessionId, encouragementDetails) {
logger.info('Services.Encouragement.index.addEncouragement', {'session-id': sessionId});
let user = await permissions.validatePermissionForSessionId(sessionId, 'addEncouragement');
//check if to user have the permissions
if(user != null) {
    let encouragement = new encouragementModel();
    encouragement.active = encouragementDetails.active;
    encouragement.numOfProducts = encouragementDetails.numOfProducts;
    encouragement.rate = encouragementDetails.rate;

    //check if all the products id belongs to products
    for (let i = 0; i < encouragementDetails.products.length; i++) {
       let exist = await dal.getProductById(encouragementDetails.products[i]);
       if(exist == null){
           return {'encouragement': null, 'code': 404, 'err': 'product not found'};
       }
    }

    //create id object from the string id
    let products = await dal.getProductsById(encouragementDetails);
    encouragement.products = products;

    let res = await dal.addEncouragement(encouragement);
    return {'encouragement': encouragement, 'code': 200, 'err': null};
}
else{
    return {'encouragement': null, 'code': 401, 'err': 'permission denied'};
}
```

};

and here's a beginning of the file:

```
"use strict";
var _regenerator = require('babel-runtime/regenerator');
var _regenerator2 = _interopRequireDefault(_regenerator);
var _asyncToGenerator2 = require('babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator');
var _asyncToGenerator3 = _interopRequireDefault(_asyncToGenerator2);
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

i would appreciate any help or if someone could tell me whats wrong here and why i cant debug properly

thank you

Comment: Not sure that it is possible, to make debug work for 100% using source maps. Have similar problem, but it never cause a real trouble.

Comment: Have no idea what's can going wrong. In my case I can debug all of my code, but sometimes it have tricky debugging. For an example, it wrap if-else into function (or may be in two functions) and after `else` block it going back to line with `if` statement. But realy, it never make troubles.

Comment: Have one idea - search for some place with bad debug behavior, than go to sources and rewrite it to simple javascript, (without `let` `const`, etc)

Comment: What debugger are you using, first off?

Comment: im writing my project in WebStorm so im using its debugger